# Error going from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-intent, onclick, onclicklistener, calculator

App is crashing when i am trying to go from one activity to another.
here is the code. i have used intent before to go from one activity to another so i know that code is right. my app is a simple calculator but when user type a secret password app goes from calculator to another activity

```
equal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            val2 = Integer.parseInt(temp);
            sp = getSharedPreferences("passinfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            if(temp.equals(sp.getString("pass",""))){
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Privatefolder.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }

            else if(val1 == null || val2 == null){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                if(operator.equals("+") ){
                    result = val1 + val2;
                }
                if(operator.equals("-")){
                    result = val1 - val2;
                }
                if(operator.equals("*")){
                    result = val1 * val2;
                }
                if(operator.equals("/")){
                    result = val1/val2;
                }
                temp1 = temp1 +" = " +result.toString();
                t1.setText(temp1);
                temp="";temp1="";
            }
        }
    });
```

i have also registered activity in manifest file

```
<activity android:name=".Privatefolder"></activity>
```

i am also using onclick methods like this. does that have to do something with the app crashing? when user clicks on any button named from 0 to 9 this method runs.

```
  protected void onClicknumbers(View v){
    Button b = (Button) v;
    if(temp1.equals("")) {
        temp += b.getText();
        t2.setText(temp);
    }
    else{
        temp += b.getText().toString();
        temp1 += b.getText();
        t1.setText(temp1);
    }

}
```

this is the error i am getting

```
11-04 20:44:22.744 16989-16989/com.dreamfighter.vault E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: com.dreamfighter.vault, PID: 16989
                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dreamfighter.vault/com.dreamfighter.vault.Privatefolder}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2572)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:204)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
                                                                        at com.dreamfighter.vault.Privatefolder.onCreate(Privatefolder.java:18)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6309)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Comment: Please include the error message from the logcat with your post.

Comment: The line that tells you what you need to know :: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.`

Comment: kindly tell me how to set windowactionbas false

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using your own custom toolbar in the Privatefolder activity if this is the case then you must declare a theme for your app that say no action bar

so go to **res/values/styles.xml**   and open this folder you will see at the top something like that

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="something here">
```

(something here) is the default theme that you will find.

change line to this

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```